# doxygen nested \if \endif sample not working

Tags: doxygen

The nested if/endif sample seems not to work as expected:

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdif

It produces:

```
Unconditionally shown documentation. More text. Unconditional text.
```

But I would expect:

```
Unconditionally shown documentation. Unconditional text.
```

I tried several doxygen versions (also the currently latest v1.8.6).
Does this sample work for anybody?

As a workaround I used:

```
  /*! Unconditionally shown documentation.
   *  \if Cond1
   *    Only included if Cond1 is set.
   *  \endif
   *  \if Cond2
   *    Only included if Cond2 is set.
   *  \endif
   *  \if (Cond2 && Cond3)
   *    Only included if Cond2 and Cond3 are set.
   *  \endif
   *  \if Cond2
   *    More text.
   *  \endif
   *  Unconditional text.
   */
```

But I would prefer to use the nested style from the original sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the example should have worked, but apparently it never did and you are the first to notice!

Please file a bug report for this in the bug tracker here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen

Comment: I've made a bug report: [link](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=722603)